# jQuery EasyTab: How to fadein/fadeout by the content class instead of the content id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [jQuery EasyTab](https://github.com/JangoSteve/jQuery-EasyTabs) to fadein/fadeout contents on hashchange function. I have multiple contents with same class names also there are 2 or 3 class names in one content. So I want to change the ID into Class.

```
<div id="tab-container" class='tab-container'>
  <ul class='etabs'>
    <li class='tab'><a href="#tab1">HTML Markup</a></li>
    <li class='tab'><a href="#tab2">Required JS</a></li>
    <li class='tab'><a href="#tab3">Example CSS</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class='panel-container'>
    <div id="tab1">
      <p>content 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
      <p>content 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3">
      <p>content 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- I want to change the panel-container section like this-->

<div class='panel-container'>
  <div class="tab1 tab3">
    <p>content 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab2">
    <p>content 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab3 tab1">
    <p>content 1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```